# IText7 html2pdf footer CSS does not work

Tags: html, css, itext, itext7

I  am not able to see footer in resultant PDF for below HTML and CSS. This code works fine with **IText version 2**.

Does the way to show header and footer is changed in **IText version 7**? or am I missing any configuration required for newer version?

Thanks.

**Java code**

```
public void createPdf(String src, String dest, String resources) throws IOException {
try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
        //Add metadata
        writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));

        // pdf conversion
        ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();

        MediaDeviceDescription mediaDeviceDescription =
            new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.PRINT);
        props.setMediaDeviceDescription(mediaDeviceDescription);

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdfDoc, props);
        pdfDoc.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Html content**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <style type="text/css" media="print">

        #footer {
            display: block;
            position: running(footer);
            color:gray;
            font-size: 50%
        }

        @page {
            @bottom-center {
                content: element(footer);
            }
            margin-bottom : 1in;
            size: 6in 6in;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">
This is the text that goes at the bottom of every page.
</div>

....
..
.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing everything right. It wasn't working for you because running elements (`position: running(..)` and `content: element(..)` properties) support is added only in the latest version, **iText 7.1.2**. It was released in the end of April.

Comment: I am using 7.1.7 and @page doesnot work in order to make it work documentation says to setMediaDeviceDescription to MediaType.PRINT and wrap it @meda{@page{}} still doesnt work