# IText7 html2pdf fixed footer using CSS

Tags: html, css, itext, itext7, html-to-pdf

I am currently trying to convert HTML to PDF using itext7 and itext7.pdfhtml but have a small problem.

I have a fixed footer (.footer) which works well when opened with a browser but when converted using below code, the div is not fixed to the bottom of the page. The div sits just after the other div content before it.

C# .net core code

```
string fullBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("index.html"); 
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(stream);
writer.SetCloseStream(false); 
iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(fullBody , writer);
writer.Close();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> 
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="header">
        <img src="header1.bmp" width="100%" />
        <img src="header2.bmp" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    ... 
    <div class="footer">
        Fixed footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;  
    text-align: center;
}
```

Have tried several other examples but it still won't stay at the bottom.

Even this similar question [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749409/itext7-html2pdf-footer-css-does-not-work) doesnt work

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In PDF
[image: in pdf]

In browser (print view)
[image]

Just a small note - this pdf will only have 1 page so a hard coded solution might be considered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The footers belong to the page margin area. `@page` media is the right way to configure it. CSS `running` element functionality can be used to put the element into the desired location and exclude it from the rest of the layout. Major tools converting HTML into page-based representation support it.

Here is a sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #footer {
                position: running(footer);
            }

            @page {
                @bottom-center {
                    content: element(footer);
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Hello world</p>

        <div id="footer">I am a footer</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Result looks like this:

[image: result]

Comment: What a coincidence, have just solved it exactly like you posted. Before I had margin-bottom:0 inside the @Page which was somehow hiding the footer!!